# Enable/disable input text gerados atraves de um loop com dados recebidos da base de dados

Tags: php, javascript

A imagem é um exemplo do que pretendo. Quando é `checkado` a `checkbox` de `verificaçãoAntiga`, torna a `Text` de `Versao Nova` ativa. Ele faz isso na primeira mas não nas outras. Alguém me consegue ajudar?

```
<?php
include('conect.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `op` WHERE `type` = 2 ;");

   echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'id='datatables-example'>

      <tr>        
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 1</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 2</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Check 1</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 3</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>VCheck 2</b></td>              
     </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {

        echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>
        <tr>
        <td>' . $row['Op'] . '</td>
        <td>  <input type='text' name='T2' class='form-control'></td>
        <td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='C1' id='C1' ></td>
        <td>  <input type='text' name='T3' id='T3' class='form-control' disabled ></td>
        <td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='C2'></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>   
       }
        </table>";
        mysqli_close($conn);   
?>




<script language ="JavaScript">                                                      
document.getElementById('C1').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('T3').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

[image: Exemplo de problema]


Se não fui bem explicito no que pretendia, perguntem por favor. Obrigado.

Comment: Você está usando Jquery ou só Javascript puro ? O problema é que todos os checks tem o mesmo id, então getElement retorna o primeiro elemento da árvore DOM, você precisa gerar ids únicos e passar isso pra função

Comment: A solução mais simples é colocar o JS dentro do loop, e gerar dinamicamente os IDs. Para não ficar repetindo JS, poderia colocar um data-attribute nos checkboxes indicando o ID do text correspondente, ou simplesmente usar seletores para pegar o textbox vizinho (neste caso, sujeito a problemas se reestruturar o HTML). Aí poderia usar um JS só para todos os campos.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ter o mesmo ID para mais do que um elemento em HTML.
Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Sugiro você selecioná-los através de uma classe:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Answer (score 1):

Atribua um id único para cada elemento durante a geração do código HTML e altere sua função Javascript

Por exemplo:

**HTML:**

```
Antigo 1<input type="checkbox" id="antigo-1" />
Novo 1<input type="checkbox" id="novo-1"  />
<br/>
Antigo 2<input type="checkbox" id="antigo-2" />
Novo 2<input type="checkbox" id="novo-2"  />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id.split("-");
  if(id[0]=="antigo"){
    $("#novo-"+id[1]).prop('checked',false);
  }else{
    $("#antigo-"+id[1]).prop('checked',false);
  }
});
```

[Fiddle Funcionando.](https://jsfiddle.net/fpxmpfav/1/)

Comment: Eu já implementei um `javascript` semelhante a esse mas não resultou.

Comment: Como não funcionou ? Você usou está usando jquery ?

Comment: Sim, estou a usar jquery

Comment: Que erro você tem ? é só você atribuir um no loop (PHP), `<input type='text' name='T2' id='antigo-$id' class='form-control'></td> <input type='text' name='T3' id='novo-$id' class='form-control'></td>` esse id pode ser um id do banco ou um numero que esteja incrementando no loop

Comment: Já consegui resolver o assunto. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @djva Se alguma das respostas ajudou você a resolver o problema, por favor marque-a como correta, desta forma outros com o mesmo problema saberão mais facilmente a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O que tá acontecendo nesse caso é que você está usando o ID do elemento para fazer a sua lógica, o problema é que todos os elementos estão com o mesmo ID, te recomendo fazer de uma outra forma:

tire o código java script de dentro do seu loop, e no final da página adicione:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[name='C1']");
        for(i in elements) {
            elements[i].onchange = function() {
                this.parentNode.nextSibling.querySelector("[name='T3']").disabled = !this.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Dessa forma você não vai ter uma repetição do código do javascript para cada volta que o loop der, e isso vai funcionar corretamente para qualquer quantidade de itens que você tiver na página.

OBS.: Tentei fazer de um jeito que acompanhasse a lógica do seu código, e também os nomes que você tá usando (dica: com jquery seria muito mais simples e legível)!

Edit---

Exemplo com jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[name='C1']").change(function() {
            $(this).closest().next().find("[name='T3']").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Como faria em jquery?

Comment: O `script ` naoesta dentro do meu ´loop´, até porque o meu ´loop´ é feito em ´php´ e nao iria colocar ´javascript´ no seu interior.

Comment: É verdade, confundi, editei o código, tenta colocar esse script no final do seu documento para ver se te ajuda!